# How to access resource object when being utilised by a service?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I am currently trying to model a set of stores with the following Agents:

- Customers
- Employees

I want to utilise a state chart to show what role (service) the employee is currently undertaking

- Cashier
- Inventory

However, I cannot find any way to access the Employee agent when it's being utilised by a service, all of the method in the service's "Actions" section refer to the Customer agent.

When Employees are not being used, they are held in a Resource Pool. Customers are injected into an entry point from the top-level agent.

In essence, when the Employee agent is working at a service, I want to be able to set its statechart to reflect what service it is being used in.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the employee on the "on seize unit" of the service block by using the following synthax

```
((Employee)unit).statechart
```

the unit variable represents your employee, but since unit is actually defined as a general agent, you need to cast it into the type you want, that's why you do ((Employee)unit) from there you can access anything you want from the employee agent

Comment: This is very helpful and greatly appreciated. One thing I noticed is that the service itself has no on release action, lo and behold I found it in the resource pool!